# Git Archive of local Git repository

Tags: linux, git, unix

I have a Git repository on a server and on the same server I have a script which needs to do a `git archive` of the repository.

Here's my sample `git archive` command which works well for remote Git repositories:

```
sudo git archive --remote=ssh://uname@dev.example.com/var/repo/myrepo.git --format=tar --output=src.tar development
```

What would I need to do/change to execute the aforementioned command on the same server so that I don't need to put all the SSH stuff? Since the command is running on the same machine as the repository, can I get away with directly accessing the Git directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use

```
cd .../yourcode
sudo git archive --format=tar --output=src.tar development
```

*(it is probably unnecessary to `sudo`)*

Comment: +1 for example command. (I'll leave my post up in case some users prefer the prose version.)

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Just run `git archive` from the directory that contains the local repo, and don't specify `--remote`.

Answer (score 0):

From the directory that is your git repository run:
git archive  | bzip2 > full/relative/or/qualified/path/to/place/you/want/to/store/your/archive.tar.bz2